# Fatal Error PHP Call to Function Undefined Multi-Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I added Wordpress SEO by Yoast to a website.Turns out the site wasn't compatible with the plugin.

The following error message is displayed:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_multisite() in /home2/(websitedomain)/public_html/events/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/inc/class-wpseo-options.php on line 2899

It's not letting me access plugin section to disable or remove the plugin.
I went through the database, and I deleted the plugin files, but I still see the error message of the website.

How do I get the incompatible plugin totally off the website?

Comment: You have to disable the plugin in the database.

Comment: How do I disable the plugin in the database?

Comment: Wordpress strikes again!

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? `is_multisite()` was introduced in version 3.0.

Comment: It feels like an ancient version of Wordpress. haha They want website design in the future for now, so I am holding off on updating their version.

Comment: For some reason, it kept reloading the error message. As soon as I deleted the files in cache, the error message went away. I could finally see that I was successful in disabling/removing the plugin through the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have actually the possibility to look at a wordpress database, so I only can give you a very general explanation :

- Use phpmyadmin
- look for the table with the plugin data (named wp_plugins or similar)
- There is a field that indicates if the plugin is active. Set it to zero for the plugin you want to disable.

Comment: I will give it a try. PhpMyAdmin is new to me.